# How to add email address as child in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on an Android App where I want a Firebase database like 
[image]

Basically, I want to verify email before creating a user on the app. Whenever a user registers in my app, First it will be checked whether the email address is available in the **users** database reference. if available, then only he is allowed to register.
But I found that Firebase doesn't allow an email as a child. So How can I do it? Any other suggestion for achieving this in Firebase Database.

Answer (score 11):

Because Firebase does not allow symbols as `.` in the key, I suggest you encode the email address like this:

> name@email.com -> name@email,com

As you probably see, instead of `.` I have used `,`. To achieve this, you can use the following methods:

```
static String encodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(".", ",");
}

static String decodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(",", ".");
}
```

Comment: yes, the problem is solved.

Comment: Happy  to hear that. So if you still consider my answer helped you in any way,  consider accepting it. Thanks!