# Email as id in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Instead of using `push()` to generate `id` for `child(user)`, can I use email of user as `id` in Firebase?

I tried this:

```
    private void userData(String emai1, String pass, String bal) {

    String id = emai1;
    int balance=Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(bal));
    User user1 = new User(id,emai1,pass,balance);
    databaseReference.child(id).setValue(user1);

}
```

User class:

```
public class User {

 private String email;
 private int balance;
 private String password;
 private String id;

public User( String id,String email, String password , int balance) {
    this.email = email;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.password = password;
    this.id = id;
}



public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public int getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(int balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

Since I have used firebase auth, user gets registered but his info does not get added to firebase database.

Btw, before trying this, I was using `push()` to get the `id` and everything was working fine, but I want email as `id` instead generating a new `id`(since emails are unique anyway.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863398/how-to-add-email-address-as-child-in-firebase, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713039/can-we-have-email-id-as-key-in-firebase-database?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an email as unique key since it contains a dot `.` which is not allowed in the database.

Since you used firebase authentication then just use the user unique id instead of `push()`

```
 FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
 String userId=user.getUid();
```

This will give you the id, which you can then use in the database also.

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId);
ref.child("name").setValue("name_here");
ref.child("email").setValue("email_here");
```

Then you would have:

```
users
  userId
    name: name_here
    email: email_here
```

Check this also:

[Why use UID in Firebase? Should I use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48379888/why-use-uid-in-firebase-should-i-use-it)